# Proving a complex function is constant in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm still a bit confused as to what aspects of real analysis are preserved or change in complex analysis.
Particularly, to prove that a function is constant, in complex analysis there's, for example:

> **Louville's Theorem:** An *entire* and *bounded* function must be *constant*.
>
> **Isolated Zeros:** If an analytical function $f$ of conex domain has any zero that isn't isolated, then $f$ is the nule function (constant and equal to 0).

But does it also hold that if a function's first derivative is null ($f'(z)=0, \forall z \in \mathbb{C})$, then the function is constant? How can I prove that is/isn't true?

Comment: @PierreCarre was that not correct? I recall “bounded entire function is constant”.

Comment: i've corrected it!

Answer (score 2):

You are not stating Liouvilles's Theorem correctly... Is says that if $f$ is entire and bounded, it must be a constant. It is also true that if $f'(z)=0$ in some connected set $\Omega$, $f$ must be constant on that set.

These two statements do not conflict.